# Does Dijkstra's "Case against the GOTO statement" apply just as much to modern day calling of named encapsulations of code as functions?

Tags: javascript, syntax, dijkstra, goto

I don't know how it worked back in the day, so I've no idea what he was referring to.

But, take JS:

```
var x = 5;
var foo = function(y) { console.log(2); };
var y = 6;
foo(); // is this not in essence a goto statement?
```

If not, then what was different about GOTO statements?

Would Dijkstra have opposed JS on these grounds?

Comment: _"I've no idea what he was referring to"_ - Perhaps doing some research on what a GOTO statement actually is would help you here. Note that at the time Dijkstra's letter was published there were languages that allowed functions/sub-routines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are calling a subroutine rather than unconditionally and permanently transferring the flow of control (which is what `goto` does).

If you put code after `foo();`, that code would get executed after `foo()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is in essence a "GOSUB" statement. Did you read the original paper? IMHO Dijkstra was offended by "smearing" state all over your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a jump statement, not a GOTO statement. Therefore, it does NOT create spaghetti code.

Comment: How did GOTOs differ from these?

Comment: The function contexts are kept in a stack which allows you to keep track of where we were, and doesn't permanently transfer the flow as NPE said.